# Is it possible to train a dog to never bark

Tags: dogs, training, vocalizations

My dog barks all the time and it gets very annoying. He is a Jack Russel Terrier mix. Is there a way I can train it to never bark?

Thank You

Comment: Animals are no robots, you cannot "switch off" certain behaviors. You need to analyze the cause for the current behavior and work at eliminating the cause. When exactly does your dog bark? "Always" is not a valid answer. Is it when there are people around? When he's bored? When he wants something from you? Please [edit] your question to provide more information.

Comment: To add to @Elmy's comment, this is a dogs main way of communicating, why would you want to stop that? Chances are there is something behind the barking that he is trying to communicate. At a broad guess, boredom but there could be other reasons you need to flesh out your question more.

Comment: Here is a way to stop all barking, *but I strongly advise against it*. Consider this a warning.

A friend bought a battery powered collar that gave his dog a little shock whenever he barked. Well, it eventually resulted in the dog's death when he got himself caught in a fence. He didn't bark, and he was found months later.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can definitely train a dog to never bark. The simplest way is to yell at it every time it barks. I do not recommend this method, but a college friend did this with his dog and in adulthood the dog still never barks, it just makes weird whiny noises instead. Usually positive reinforcement is a much better way to train a happy dog, so I would start with training it to stop barking on a command and then use that command CONSISTENTLY every time you hear the dog bark. Clicker training can be very useful for this. If you're not clicker training for other things I would suggest starting with training your dog that every time it hears a click it gets a treat, then work to clicking and giving a treat every time it stops barking when you say "quiet." Consistency is the key here, as you're trying to train your dog not to do something that is at its very core.